# Anybody have a step-by-step install instructions of SSL Owncloud on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache2, ssl

Anybody have a step-by-step install instructions of SSL Owncloud on Ubuntu 16.04?

I've literally been at this for days unable to install... please also notes that 16.04 is using php7 by default.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Have you already installed Owncloud ?

Comment: yes I've installed it. Can't get access to it remotely outside of LAN

Comment: Have you forwarded the port on your router ?